# Strange temporary recurring flashes on the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair

So, I've been using my MacBook Pro (2019 15 inch) for quite a while now(somewhere about 6 months. Recently, I've started to notice strange blinking ringlike flickers on my screen that occur literally out of nowhere and for no apparent reason. They usually persist for like 30 minutes and then disappear after I reboot the laptop multiple times. Can you please help me with identifying the underlying reason for that? I include a photo of my screen and also here is a link to the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V9jnmmugM2Og16_j0Da_R3C1nEi_0vQv/view?usp=sharing

P.S. I did not spill anything on my screen nor did I somehow scratch it or damage it.

[image]

Comment: This has the feel of a hardware malfunction, IMHO. Does everything on the screen have this jitter? You only show a small icon(?) on a small part of the screen, and its hard to tell whet else is happening. Have you dropped it recently? What are you doing when this happens? Is there any correlation with a specific app or apps running and the appearance of the flicker effect? When this happens again, open QuickTime Player and do a screen capture for a minute or so. If the recorded video is non-twitchy, then I'd have to point to HW being at issue.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thank you for the info. No, it does not record those twitches. It occurs without any correlation with any app. I have not dropped it or somehow damaged it. It occurs only in one specific place and is not multiple. What do you suggest I should do with my hardware? Just get it repaired? If so, are prices steep for this type of a repair?

Comment: It might still be under warrantee!

Answer (score 1):

First, Make sure your MacOS is up to date in [System Pref -> Software Update].

Try disabling the auto brightness in **[System Pref -> Display]** (automatically adjust brightness); and **[System Pref -> Keyboard]** (adjust keyboard in low light).

If you have a custom color profile, switch to the default "color LCD" one in [System Pref -> Display -> Color]. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsK5zmRpg5k

Resetting PRAM might also help: Reboot, hold CMD + Opt + P + R until the apple logo shows, then let go. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5laIcLMnJU

Create a guest account or new user in [System Pref -> Users & Groups] use the + icon to create one. Press the Apple logo at the top left to [log out] and test using the new account.

You can also try running the Apple Diagnostics test to see if there's a hardware problem by restarting and holding "D" until it boots up.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/diagnose-problems-mh35727/mac
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8y_pcaw_Ac

For hardware-related repairs: If you have AppleCare+, it wouldn't hurt to get a price quote, because **2016+ MacBooks have a T2 chip that rejects non-Apple certified hardware repairs and parts**. If looks like the minimum cost for a repair for the screen could be $99-$300. https://support.apple.com/mac/repair/service
This site says to expect around $455+ for an out of warranty screen repair.
https://www.gophermods.com/how-much-does-it-cost-to-replace-a-macbook-screen-at-the-apple-store/

Hope this helps! Best of luck!